# Is there a faithful functor from the freely generated bicartesian closed category to $\mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Does there exist a *faithful* (bicartesian closed) functor $\operatorname F$ from the freely generated bicartesian closed category $\mathbf B$ to $\mathbf{Set}$? Preferably, $\mathbf B$ should contain exactly the objects, arrows and commuting diagrams required by a bicartesian closed category, and nothing else, but other reasonable definitions are also welcome.

Put another way: does the free generation of arrows in $\mathbf B$, restricted only by its bicartesian closed structure, produce more arrows than there are arrows in $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: Unless ${\bf B}$ fails to be small, the functor $$X\longmapsto \{g:U\to X|g\in{\bf Hom}_{\bf B}\},$$ $$f:X\to Y\longmapsto f\circ,$$ yields a faithful functor into ${\bf Set}$. Further, even if this category fails to be small in e.g. $ZFC$, we can shift to a universe-based setting and get what we need by restricting attention to a version of ${\bf B}$ inside a fixed universe and be good to go.

Comment: What is a bicartesian closed category? What is a bicartesian closed functor?

Comment: Isn't $B$ just the category of finite sets? The objects that $B$ is required to contain are initial and terminal objects $0, 1$, then it has to be freely closed under finite products, coproducts, and exponentials. Since product distributes over coproduct, closure under finite products + coproducts produces exactly finite coproducts of copies of $1$, and the behavior of exponentials on two such objects is uniquely determined. Am I missing something?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan [This other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460203/17064), that I just asked, is partly an attempt to make precise sense of the present one (which, as you point out, seems a bit strange).

Comment: @TimCampion: a [bicartesian closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicartesian+closed+category) is a cartesian closed category with finite coproducts. (The corresponding notion of functor is then clear.)